# Python: Hash function always produces same (empty) hash for any file

Tags: python, file, hash

So I did a ton of googling around but can't really find an answer to my problem.
I tried to make a function to hash bigger files, and I made two different functions, yet both seem to produce the same output for any file I hash, to be precise:

`e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`

which I know is the SHA256 hash of an empty bite string.

The two solutions I tried to use were:

```
from hashlib import sha256 as hashfun

bs = 1048576                   # I'll just use 1024kb chunks as an example
selectfile = "/PATH/TO/FILE"

with open(selectfile, 'rb') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(bs), b''):
        hashfun().update(chunk)
    print(hashfun().hexdigest())
```

and

```
from hashlib import sha256 as hashfun

bs = 1048576
selectfile = "/PATH/TO/FILE"

with open(selectfile, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(bs)
        if not data:
            break
        hashfun().update(data)
    print(hashfun().hexdigest())
```

Neither of these seems to function.
I know that the file is not the issue since a simple function without the block reading worked before:

```
from hashlib import sha256 as hashfun

selectfile = "/PATH/TO/FILE"

with open(selectfile, 'rb') as f:
    rbytes = f.read()
    readable_hash = hashfun(rbytes).hexdigest()
    print(readable_hash)
```

Is there something super obvious that I am doing wrong here (probably lol)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is *calling* the hash constructor repeatedly instead of creating a single hash instance and updating it.

This should work:

```py
from hashlib import sha256 as hashfun

bs = 1048576                   # I'll just use 1024kb chunks as an example
selectfile = "/PATH/TO/FILE"
hash_ = hashfun()

with open(selectfile, 'rb') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(bs), b''):
        hash_.update(chunk)
    print(hash_.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Ohhhh, yeah that makes absolute sense lol
I was wondering if that may be the difference between all the code that I saw and my own code.
Thanks!